# How to upload video to youtube specific channelID in C#

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I am able to successfully upload a video to my youtube account in C# using the following code:

```
        private async Task Run(string videoFile, string dateStamp)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner},
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = string.Format("{0} - La Jolla boat launch timelapse", dateStamp);
        video.Snippet.Description = "Daily TimeLapse of the boat launch area.";
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "LaJolla", "timelapse" };
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
        video.Snippet.ChannelId = "UC8LB7gACPEoNxdAK6LM-L6A";
        video.Snippet.ChannelTitle = "TimeLapse La Jolla";
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"
        var filePath = videoFile; // Replace with path to actual movie file.


        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

            await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
```

However, I have 3 channels in my youtube account and would like to upload to a specific channel.  The code above will upload to my main account without issue, but not to the channel ID supplied.  The channel name and ID are correct - but this is not working as I expected the video to appear as a new upload in the channel.  I am not able to find additional information for this functionality.  Any suggestions?

Code is from youtube API samples.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: I have not.  However, I have taken an alternate approach to upload videos using google's smtp server.

Comment: I should also mention that I created an entirely different youtube account vs. channel and upload via e-mail/smtp to that account.

Comment: How Can I set policyId ? I need to enable monitize in my videos from upload...

Comment: @thiago.adriano26 - you should consider submitting a new SO question.  Only those following this question (if any) and myself will see your question.

Comment: got It, thank's ;) I'll create...

Comment: oAuth says Accessdenied any using above code any one plz post sample? can we upload using APIKey instead of oAuth?

Comment: The sample code above works with oAuth - are you getting prompted to use a google account?